# How to resolve errors while installing magento 2 for the first time with php, nginx and mysql

Tags: installation, magento2

I am trying to setup Magento 2 on my windows 10 machine via Ubuntu WSL. As of yet I have successfully installed PHP 7.4, MySQL 8.0 and NGINX. While installing Magento 2, I get the following error -

```
An exception was raised while creating "Application"; no instance returned#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback()
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory()
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate()
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create()
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(261): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get()
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Console/Cli.php(72): Zend\Mvc\Application::init()
#6 /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento(24): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct()
#7 {main}

An exception was raised while creating "Request"; no instance returned#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback()
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory()
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate()
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create()
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(113): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get()
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ApplicationFactory.php(29): Zend\Mvc\Application->__construct()
#6 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Service\ApplicationFactory->createService()
#7 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(939): call_user_func()
#8 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback()
#9 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory()
#10 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate()
#11 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create()
#12 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(261): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get()
#13 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Console/Cli.php(72): Zend\Mvc\Application::init()
#14 /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento(24): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct()
#15 {main}

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/ArrayObject.php on line 426#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler()
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include()
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#3 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/Parameters.php(29): spl_autoload_call()
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-console/src/Request.php(96): Zend\Stdlib\Parameters->__construct()
#6 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-console/src/Request.php(122): Zend\Console\Request->getParams()
#7 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-console/src/Request.php(66): Zend\Console\Request->params()
#8 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/RequestFactory.php(29): Zend\Console\Request->__construct()
#9 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Service\RequestFactory->createService()
#10 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(939): call_user_func()
#11 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback()
#12 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory()
#13 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate()
#14 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create()
#15 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(113): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get()
#16 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ApplicationFactory.php(29): Zend\Mvc\Application->__construct()
#17 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Service\ApplicationFactory->createService()
#18 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(939): call_user_func()
#19 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback()
#20 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory()
#21 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate()
#22 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create()
#23 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(261): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get()
#24 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Console/Cli.php(72): Zend\Mvc\Application::init()
#25 /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento(24): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct()
#26 {main}
```

I am following the guide provided in link - https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-nginx/#Step_4_Configure_nginx . I am getting the error while executing the step 7 in guide.

I tried researching these errors but all are pointing towards an issue in upgrade while this is a first time I am installing magento. I proceeded to executing step 8 but still getting the same set of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please run this and paste the output?

```
php -m
```

I took a quick look at that guide and it doesn't seem that it tells you to install all the necessary PHP extensions for Magento 2.

P.S. There are two different steps #7 in the guide. If you are stuck in the second one, run the following command and post the output here:

```
sudo systemctl status nginx
```

Comment: akurian@S01155:~$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mhash
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache

Comment: akurian@S01155:~$ sudo systemctl status nginx
[sudo] password for akurian:
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Comment: Yeah, you are missing required PHP modules for magento. Try running this:

`yum -y install php74u-pdo php74u-mysqlnd php74u-opcache php74u-xml php74u-gd php74u-devel php74u-mysql php74u-intl php74u-mbstring php74u-bcmath php74u-json php74u-iconv php74u-soap`



Also, please refer to [this document for more info.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html)

Comment: i used the command you provided to install packages but it says unable to locate package -